# How does Differential backups knows about full backup

Tags: sql-server, azure

In my environment we have SQL Servers in Azure IAAS. We use netbackup as backuptool. we have an issue where differential backups were failing with the error saying that.

> cannot find the Full backup.

So when investigated, azure VM level backups are running which is affecting the backup chain in the database level. For testing purposes I stopped the SQL VSS writer on a server and the VM level backups did not affect the database Level backups. Differential with netbackup was successful. But now I saw there is a native job (Ola helengren-not copy_only) backing up the databases but it didn't cause any problem to the Netbackup differential backups. I even tested it clearly taking a full backup through a native job and taking a differential through netbackup.

How come?

Comment: Is your Azure SQL backups got a retention period set? It might be possible that the full backup had exceeded the retention timeline and was removed.

Comment: it has 7 days retention period,..but does it matter..because backups through azure are different than native right?

Comment: A SQL Server backup running on a VM is a SQL Server backup. Doesn't matter if the VM is in Azure, AWS, Google Cloud, or running on your local hardware. It's all just SQL Server. Sounds like someone set up Ola Hollengren's scripts on your system. That's not native to Azure. So something else is happening.

Comment: yeah..but the Backup happening is Azure VM Backups,that Vm Level backup is causing an issue with Netbackup differential backup.i checked and NO OLA Script was scheduled or ran..

Comment: We had found the issue. The Azure VM backups was the culprit..it was taking backup of whole VM and when it comes to SQL, it takes SQL Backups and breaks the chain.. But still i am not getting the point how native full backup didnt affect Netbackup differential backups.